# SQL - how to get specific order on a specific date in two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

We were asked to create a SQL statement  to show total order amount of the order that Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery placed on 1997-01-01.. However, the ORDERS table is different from the CUSTOMERS table.

So here's what I did:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, 
    Orders.CustomerID, 
    Orders.EmployeeID, 
    Orders.OrderDate, 
    Orders.ShipperID, 
    Customers.CustomerID, 
    Customers.CustomerName, 
    Customers.ContactName, 
    Customers.Address, 
    Customers.City, 
    Customers.PostalCode, 
    Customers.Country
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
WHERE DATE = 1997-01-01
```

But it's showing me an 'error' sign. How to fix this? The error says: 'could not prepare'.

Here's the link for the database: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: MS SQL Server or MySQL? They are very different in many aspects of SQL.

Comment: Add single qoutes arround the date.

Comment: Show the error message

Comment: `WHERE DATE = '1997-01-01'`

Comment: You should use a table or alias to qualify the `DATE` column.  Also, what is the column representing the order amount?  Presumably, you want to do some aggregation but it is not clear.

Comment: can it be that the where Statement must be `Orders.OrderDate = '1997-01-01'`

Comment: @Jens I tried that too and it's still not working.

Comment: @KyleSanchez `not working` is not enough Information. We need the sal error message

Comment: @Jens: I keep on getting the Error 1: Could not prepare statement.

Comment: @KyleSanchez There must be more informations. Can you also put the table create Statements to your question?

Comment: there is no date column in any of your table

Answer (score 1):

You **haven't any DATE column** in any of your table, please **Replace** DATE column to **Orders.OrderDate** and also semicolumn in wrong place

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, 
    Orders.CustomerID, 
    Orders.EmployeeID, 
    Orders.OrderDate, 
    Orders.ShipperID, 
    Customers.CustomerID, 
    Customers.CustomerName, 
    Customers.ContactName, 
    Customers.Address, 
    Customers.City, 
    Customers.PostalCode, 
    Customers.Country
FROM Customers 
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate= '1997-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add quotes on `date` and a wrong place to add a semicolon.

```
 SELECT Orders.OrderID, 
        Orders.CustomerID, 
        Orders.EmployeeID, 
        Orders.OrderDate, 
        Orders.ShipperID, 
        Customers.CustomerID, 
        Customers.CustomerName, 
        Customers.ContactName, 
        Customers.Address, 
        Customers.City, 
        Customers.PostalCode, 
        Customers.Country
    FROM Customers
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID //u added semicolon here which is wrong
    WHERE DATE = '1997-01-01';
```

Comment: I did this and it's still not working :(. I keep on getting the Error 1: Could not prepare statement.

Comment: Hey, U just added semicolon in wrong place. Check NOw.

Comment: As I told you, that this error comes only due to minor mistakes. Take care next time.